# Coalgebra dual to the symmetric algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, coalgebras

I'm interested in the coalgebra dual to the symmetric algebra $S(V)$ on some finite dimensional vector space $V$. I'd like to know explicitly what the comultiplication map is.

Comment: $S(V)$ is not a finite dim. algebra, so the standard construction to dualize it and getting a coalgebra does not work. It is a bialgebra, though. Is this what you are interested in? There exists a more sophisticated construction involving the exterior (co)algebra and Koszul duality, to be honest

Comment: Another interpretation of the question is to ask for the graded dual of the symmetric algebra, which is the divided power algebra, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_power.

Comment: @Avitus  I'm reading a paper by Demazure (Invariants symetriques entiers des groupes de Weyl et torsion) in which it is stated that a certain family of operators on the symmetric algebra, composed with the counit, forms a subcoalgebra of the coalgebra dual to the symmetric algebra. Furthermore, the paper says that this follows from the fact that for a given operator $f$, $f(uv) = \sum f_i'(u) f_i'(v)$ for $u,v \in S(V)$. This fact indeed would imply the result given the usual finite-dimensional case construction of the comultiplication map. I wonder why it works here despite infinite dimension

Comment: ok, wait a sec :-) let us consider $V$ to be concentrated in degree $0$; it seems we  need a "grading" on the symmetric algebra. A way to introduce something like that is to consider the "weight", i.e. integer in the canonical decomposition $S(V)=\mathbb K\oplus V\oplus V^{\otimes 2}/I\oplus\dots$ and check its compatibility with the associative product on $S(V)$. Now we have a graded unital associative algebra. Is this you context?

Comment: @Avitus  Yes that's right, $S(V)$ is considered as a graded algebra, and the dual coalgebra is also supposed to be graded.

Comment: @Avitus  I suppose that since we have the grading, and the graded components are always finite-dimensional, the standard finite dimensional construction of the comultiplication map goes through.

Comment: @Balerion_the_black yes, I think it is the right context: (non positively) graded dual coalgebra.

Comment: @Avitus Why do you call it non-positively graded? I mean I understand that $S(V)$ is non-negatively graded, so it looks like the dual should be non-positively graded, but is it just a convention, or is there some deeper meaning to the fact that the grading is non-positive?

Comment: If you have a non neg. graded vector space, say $W$, then its dual is non pos. graded, i.e.  $(W^*)_i:= (W_{-i})^*$ so the map $W\otimes W^*\rightarrow\mathbb K$ is of degree $0$.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this question as well and tried to google search for a reference. Let $S^*(V)$ denote the symmetric algebra on $V$. It is given in degree $n$ by $V^{\otimes n}/\Sigma_n$.

Let $S_n(V)$ denote the symmetric n-tensors in $V$, e.g. $S_n(V)=(V^{\otimes n})^{\Sigma_n}$ (here we do not take quotients, but fixed points).

We then have a canonical evaluation map $S^n(V^*)\otimes S_n(V)\to \mathbb{F}$ given by
$[f_1\otimes\ldots f_n](v_1\otimes \ldots \otimes v_n)=f_1(v_1)\ldots f_n(v_n)$. Note if we write a symmetric tensor as a linear combination of elementary tensors, then the summands need not be symmetric. So the upper notation is a bit sloppy.

It is easy to check that this evaluation map is well defined. Let $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ be a basis of $V$ and $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ be the dual basis. Then $f_1^{i_1}\ldots f_n^{i_n}$ is a basis for $S^n(V^*)$, where $i_*$ runs though all multi-indices adding up to $n$.

For such a multiindex $i$, we can also write down an element of $S_n(V)$ as follows.
Let $S$ be a system of representatives of $\Sigma_n/(\Sigma_{i_1}\times \ldots \times \Sigma_{i_n})$ and then look at the vector $$E_{i}:=\sum_{\sigma\in S}\sigma (e_1^{\otimes i_1}\otimes \ldots e_n^{\otimes i_n})$$. Then these bases are dual to each other.

For example, if $\dim(V)=2$ and $n=2$, we get the elements $e_1\otimes e_1,e_1\otimes e_2+e_2\otimes e_1,e_2\otimes e_2$ as a basis for $S_2(V)$.

Next the coproduct should just be the restriction of the coproduct on the tensor algebra, i.e.
$$S_n(V)\to \bigoplus_{r+s=n}S_r(V)\otimes S_s(V)$$
sending $E_i$ to $\sum_{k+l=i}E_k\otimes E_l$. Here the sum runs over all possibilites to write $i$ as a sum of two other multiindices.